# pythonでのbyteの足し算

Tags: python

`byte=bytes(str)`としてbyteに`b'\x0a\x0b\x0c'`を入れたときに、byte[2]の`b'\x0c'`に`b'\x01'`を足して`b'\x0d'`にしたいのですがどのように書けばいいでしょうか？

pythonのバージョンは、python2.7.12を使っています。
どなたかわかる方がいましたら、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ミュータブル（変更可能）なバイト配列を返す組み込み関数 [bytearray](http://docs.python.jp/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) を使うのはどうでしょうか。

```
>>> byte=bytearray(b'\x0a\x0b\x0c')
>>> byte
bytearray(b'\n\x0b\x0c')
>>> byte[2]
12
>>> byte[2]+=0x01
>>> byte
bytearray(b'\n\x0b\r')
```

Comment: 計算結果が、int型になるためバイナリにするために`pack('B',byte[2])`が必要でしたが足し算できました。